# How to create exact lvm sizes in the debian installer?

Tags: linux, debian, lvm

I am wondering how i exactly can define a logical volumes size in the debian installer.

For a vagrant basebox I try to define the lvm sizes as small as possible using `2^n` steps. `16Mb`, `32Mb`, `64Mb`, `128Mb`,... (16mb for home, 384mb for var, 128mb for opt,...)

I have tried entering them in `Kb` and `Mb`, with a notation type of `1000` and of `1024`. it's not possible for me to get the exact values.

entering a size of 16Mb, 16000kb, 16384kb results in a actual volume size of 12mb.

[image: debian installer lvm]

am i doing something wrong?

only if i enter `18mb`, `18432` i get the `16Mb` (which is the minimum size for using the xfs filesystem).

running the 64bit installer of debian jessie 8.5 in a virtualbox on windows.

edit:
also quite interesting is the jump from `62mb` to `61mb` without the possibility to reach `64mb`

[image: debian installer lvm - jump]

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. This question may be appropriate on other SE sites such as [unix.se]. Check their help first to see if the question belongs there and if so you can click the "flag" link and select "in need of moderator attention" to request migration there.

Comment: modorator flag is raised, waiting for migration